# Laravel & CDN Integreation

Tags: php, laravel, cdn

I am using the PHP framework laravel and have just purchased a plan for CDN servers.

I was wondering has anyone ever or would advice moving some of laravel's core files onto the CDN to decrease load time?

Comment: By core files, I assume you mean css, js & images? Normally core would refer to code (PHP in this case)

Comment: and expose your server-side code to everybody ? what files are you talking about ?

Comment: you can try to use [jare.io](http://www.jare.io), a free and instant CDN

Answer (score 0):

Moving the Laravel core files to CDN will *increase*, not *decrease*, your load time. Think about it - your server will need to fetch all the PHP scripts on the network, one request per file, which will amount to a huge amount of data. The PHP fopen wrappers do not support caching either, so you'll lose a major benefit of CDNs by doing this.

If you really want to reduce disk I/O (sounds like this is what you want to achieve), consider an opcode cache (memcache, eAccelerator). This caches your PHP code in RAM in its just-before-execution compiled form, which allows you to safely throw the interpretation step out of the loop on most requests, resulting in faster page loads.

Or switch to PHP5.5, though it isn't quite ready yet, as it has an opcode cache built in.

Comment: the question doesnt even make sense. CDNs are usually for static assets (images/js/css, ... ) .not for server-side code.

Comment: @mpm: You can nevertheless use a CDN for PHP files. It's stupid, but it's possible. I detailed the very reasons why it is stupid to do so... and I'll add one more: you need to enable remote PHP includes on your server for it to work, which is a huge security hole as it cannot be enabled on a per-directory basis.

Comment: sorry, I mean increase load time. But I get your point thanks. I will look into memcache for now

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CDN Assets Manager Package for Laravel, That supports Amazon S3 by default.

**https://github.com/Vinelab/cdn**

#### Install it Via Composer:

```
    {
    "require": {
        "vinelab/cdn": "*"
    }
```

#### Add your CDN Credentials:

```
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => '',
            'secret'    => '',
        ],

        'buckets' => [
            'bucket-name-here' => '*',
        ]
```

#### Specify directories, extensions, files and patterns to be uploaded

```
'include'    => [
    'directories'   => ['public/dist'],
    'extensions'    => ['.js', '.css', '.yxz'],
    'patterns'      => ['**/*.coffee'],
],
```

#### Also specify what to be ignored

```
'exclude'    => [
    'directories'   => ['public/uploads'],
    'files'         => [''],
    'extensions'    => ['.TODO', '.txt'],
    'patterns'      => ['src/*', '.idea/*'],
    'hidden'        => true, // ignore hidden files
],
```

---

#### USAGE:

1. Run this artisan command to push your assets to the CDN.

   **php artisan cdn:push**
2. Use it as follow in your Views or anywhere else in your code:

   **{{ Cdn::asset('public/assets/js/script.js') }}**

   **{{ Cdn::asset('public/assets/css/main.css') }}**